# What are the file "pointer" things, and how do I change them?

Tags: files

Apologies for the rather ambiguous title, but I wasn't familiar with what terminology I should use. When run the `ll` command in my `/usr/local/` directory I get:

```
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 Mar 10 20:29 ./
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Oct  8 13:47 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 31  2018 bin/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   19 Nov 21  2018 cuda -> /usr/local/cuda-9.0/
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 4096 Mar 10 20:30 cuda-10.1/
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 4096 Nov 21  2018 cuda-9.0/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 31  2018 etc/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 31  2018 games/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 31  2018 include/
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Dec 11  2018 lib/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Nov 19  2018 man -> share/man/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 31  2018 sbin/
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 Nov 19  2018 share/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 31  2018 src/
```

If you look at the fifth line, there's a "pointer thing" that's pointing the `cuda` file to `/usr/local/cuda-9.0/`. How do I change this to be pointing to `/usr/local/cuda-10.1/`?

Answer (score 3):

That is a [symbolic links](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-soft-link-or-symbolic-link/) or often phrased as `symlink`

> A symbolic link, also termed a soft link, is a special kind of file that points to another file, much like a shortcut in Windows or a Macintosh alias.

<sub>Excerpt from https://kb.iu.edu/d/abbe</sub>

You can update the symlink so it points to newer version of cuda, simply running following command.

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/cuda-10.1 /usr/local/cuda
```

Check if the file retain different link by execute `ll` on the terminal window, you can see that it's no longer pointing to old cuda version.